# Cual es el error en este sprintf()?

Tags: php, mysql, sprintf

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone, state, dob, rules, pepsico_news) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %u, %s)", $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $state, $dob, $rules, $pepsico_news);
```

> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '@gmail.com, 55555555555, NY, 01.10.89, 0, no)' at line 1
> ```

He tratado de encontrar el error pero no lo encuentro, seguro es algo de sintaxis pero no logro encontrarlo.

Comment: Puedes poner que valores tiene cada una de tus variables por favor? Y por ahí pusiste `%u` en ves de `%s` es eso correcto?

Comment: Posiblemente tu fallo está en que los valores deben ir entre comillas: `('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%u', '%s')`

Comment: La solución es lo que comenta @cnbandicoot, pero te diría que no hagas eso, porque hace tu código vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Es mejor que uses sentencias preparadas/parametrizadas en su lugar.

Comment: Si bien agregar `'%s'`, puede solucionar tu problema... si por esas cosas de la vida, por ejemplo, la variable `$lname` fuera igual a `D'Antuoni`, la cadena se rompería y te daría nuevamente error. Has lo que dice  @AlvaroMontoro, tiene mucha razón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar de esta manera:

```
<?php

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone, state, dob, rules, pepsico_news) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %u, '%s')", $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $state, $dob, $rules, $pepsico_news);

?>
```

Lo que al parecer esta ocurriendo es que, al realizar el reemplazo de valores en [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php), no estas agregando las **comillas**, por lo cual tu consulta de sql, estaria quedando con errores.

Mira esta ejemplo:

```
<?php

$fname = "Juan";
$lname = "Perez";
$email = "juan.perez@gmail.com";
$phone = "123456";
$state = "UK";
$dob = "dob";
$rules = 1;
$pepsico_news = "pepsico";

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone, state, dob, rules, pepsico_news) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %u, '%s')", $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $state, $dob, $rules, $pepsico_news);

print $sql;

?>
```

Si obtenemos el resultado, nos dara algo asi:

> INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone, state, dob, rules, pepsico_news) VALUES ('Juan', 'Perez', 'juan.perez@gmail.com', '123456', 'UK', 'dob', 1, 'pepsico')

Si ejecutas esta consulta, es muy probable que funcione, ya que hemos agregado todas las **comillas** respectivas, para los campos de tipo varchar.

**Pero!**

Si dejamos el mismo ejemplo, con la consulta como tu lo has preguntado:

```
<?php

$fname = "Juan";
$lname = "Perez";
$email = "juan.perez@gmail.com";
$phone = "123456";
$state = "UK";
$dob = "dob";
$rules = 1;
$pepsico_news = "pepsico";

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone, state, dob, rules, pepsico_news) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %u, %s)", $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $state, $dob, $rules, $pepsico_news);

print $sql;

?>
```

Nos arrojaria esto:

> INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phone, state, dob, rules, pepsico_news) VALUES (Juan, Perez, juan.perez@gmail.com, 123456, UK, dob, 1, pepsico)

Y probablemente la consulta no funcionara, debido a que en todos los campos donde se insertara una cadena, no estamos agregando las **comillas**. Por lo cual el motor te indicara ese error.